# How to I reduce the dimensions of a matrix by adding together subcomponents of the matrix?

Tags: r

I am doing some work with social accounting matrices. I am wanting to reduce the size of the matrix by adding components together. So for example, I want to add imported commodities to demanded commodities. It is basically a "sumifs" function with criteria displayed in rows and columns.

For example, I want to combine the rows/columns A with F and B with E by summing them up.

Simple example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hRbGlln1-MieVJ_DqY9dLr4rz6CVLvjXtwlN52LnZWM/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

In more complex data, I have two levels of names I would like to combine in various ways. For example, I would like to sum together import sales taxes, domestic sales taxes, into just sales taxes. See the data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_PlNJ_uKT34Jk0JyMK6FUmrkVVGGmpZRlxEfHqCAe9w/pub?gid=434106651&single=true&output=csv

Comment: Can you explain how these two matrices are related? (and should the last column read `F`, not `D`?)

Comment: Hi, yep the last D should be F. My actual data is a little more complicated. See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_PlNJ_uKT34Jk0JyMK6FUmrkVVGGmpZRlxEfHqCAe9w/pub?output=csv  I am wanting to do things like combine the imported commodity and the demanded commodity into a single group called "commodities" by summing them up. I also want to combine the different taxes into a single entity called government, but still keep the subcategories.

Comment: Ok, but looking at your matrix, I have no idea which columns/rows represent the imported/demanded commodities, nor which represent taxes. How does element 1 of the second matrix become 10, for example? It's worth editing your question to clarify that.

Comment: So my work around was to download the data, use the tidyr package to reformat the data in R. Reload the data and then use a pivot table to split it into the way I wanted. Not sure if there is a better way to do it but it worked.